# SkiaSharp: Unexpected results with ArcTo() and Close()

Tags: xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I'm drawing some lines and arcs using SkiaSharp on a SKCanvasView (Xamarin.Forms) under Android 11.

I create the SKPath, and it mostly renders as expected, but I'm finding that the Close() stroke always ends at the *start-point of the last-added Arc* rather than at the *1st point in the path*.

Code:

```
SKPoint pt = new SKPoint(600, 400); // Random location
float r = 100;                      // Arc radius
float d = 2 * r;                    // Side of arc rect
SKRect rc = new SKRect(pt.X, pt.Y, pt.X + d, pt.Y + d);
SKPath path = new SKPath();
path.MoveTo(rc.Right + 50, rc.Top);
path.LineTo(rc.Right, rc.MidY); // Line "S"
path.ArcTo(rc, 0, 90, true);    // Arc "A"
path.ArcTo(rc, 90, 90, true);   // Arc "B"
path.ArcTo(rc, 180, 90, true);  // Arc "C"
path.Close();                   // Line "K"

using (var skp = new SKPaint() { Style=SKPaintStyle.Stroke, IsAntialias=true, Color=SKColors.Red, StrokeWidth=6 }) {
    canv.DrawPath(path, skp);
}
```

And here's the result (non-red items added for illustration).
The thing that I don't understand is why `path.Close()` causes line "K" to end at the B/C juncture rather than at the origin of "S". I would have *expected* Close() to generate line "G" (in red, of course) rather than "K".

[image: picture]

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: from the docs for `Close()` - "If the current point is not equal to the first point of the contour, a line segment is automatically added."

Comment: @Jason Understood. After that final ArcTo() the path's LastPoint is the C/K juncture, as expected. Additionally, if I call LineTo(somewhere) after that last ArcTo(), that additional line draws from the end of C to "somewhere", as expected. And if I then call Close(), that auto-generated stroke will *still* end at the B/C juncture, even if that line is "G", explicitly ending at the origin of "S" (which should close the path, thus Close() would not generate a stroke).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Close` goes to the start *of the current contour*.

Instead of

```
path.ArcTo(rc, 0, 90, true);
```

You want

```
path.ArcTo(rc, 0, 90);
```

OR

```
path.ArcTo(rc, 0, 90, false);
```

Make this change on all of those `ArcTo` calls.

Reason:

- final parameter "true" told it to start a new `contour`!

As described in [Three ways to Draw an Arc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/curves/arcs#the-angle-arc):

```
public void ArcTo (SKRect oval, Single startAngle, Single sweepAngle, Boolean forceMoveTo)
```

> That last argument is called forceMoveTo, and it effectively causes a MoveTo call at the beginning of the arc. That begins a new `contour`.

Comment: Thanks!
In the meantime, I also experimented with
path.ArcTo(r, r, 0, SKPathArcSize.Small, SKPathDirection.Clockwise, X, Y);
and found that to "work"

Comment: @dlchambers - sure, you can go the long-way-round and use any variant that doesn't specify starting a new contour ;)

Comment: now that you've explained it, my misuse of the 'forceMoveTo' makes perfect sense. I misunderstood the docs' explanation of the param.